# Is there a checkmate in the next move?

Tags: analysis, checkmate

My friend claims that there is a mate in the next move. White to move and checkmate. I am aware of 3 mates in 2 variations:

```
1. Qd1 Kd3 2.Rxd5#

1. Qd1 Kc5 2.Qg1#

1. Qd1 Kxe5 2.d4#
```

But I cannot seem to find a mate in one move!

I ran it through Houdini and Rybka, both spat out the above variations.

I am aware that the engines dont normally miss these mate in 1 moves, still He seems to be sure (maybe he's wrong). Just want some 'experts' to confirm this.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what your friend got wrong, but `1. Qd1!` is a really nice move.

Comment: He seems to be so sure ! He says - `"Magesh Kumaar There is a single move to checkmate black. Eliminate all other factors, and the one which remains must be the truth"`

Comment: Maybe by "single move" he means "only a single move works", not "the sequence ending in checkmate is a single move"?

Comment: Chess engines NEVER miss mate-in-1. If a chess engine doesn't find it it's not there.

Answer (score 10):

It's a silly trick.  The board is upside-down!  The bottom left square is h8, and the top right is a1.  A legal move for white (but not a mate in 1) would be `1. e8=Q`.  Look at it upside-down for a minute, readjust your perception of which squares are controlled by pawns, and you'll soon find a mate in 1.

Comment: That may be the 'solution' but the board is clearly marked with a-h and 1-8. Thus, the board is *not* upside down. If this is the solution then what we have here is really a _chess variant_. At that point, anything could be possible since we don't, and can't, know the variant's rules.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: I think that the question asker made that diagram (the caption talks about "my friend") so the diagram may be wrong in this respect.

Comment: That would not be mate - Black plays Kxd4

Comment: But 1.Rd5# would indeed be mate.

Comment: Um, I was trying to explain the method of solving the problem without actually giving away the answer!  @Evargolo, would you mind editing your comment to remove the "spoiler"?

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, for mate in one, white needs to give check and guard e5. If the Q checks on b2, this opens c5 and d3 for the black K. If the Q checks on c3 or e4, it can be captured. If the Re5 checks on e4 or d5, it can be captured.

There is no mate in one.

---

However, now I look at this again, I can see that it might be the *wording of the question* that is wrong. White can certainly **end** the game in one move. f4, Kf4, Kf5, Rbf4 and any non-checking move by the Re5 will end the game.

In stalemate.

So you might say, by a trick of phrasing, that's a kind of "mate in the next move".

Answer (score 3):

There is no mate in one move here, as there is 9 (Txb4+, Txd5+, Te4+, Dc5+, Dc4+, Dc3+, Dd3+, De4+, Db2+) way to do check black king but none of them gives mate.

Also it could be very interesting to find some example where Rybka or Houdini (or others...) can miss a mate in one.

Comment: I thought the same. But he's sure of it :o [ may be he's just wrong ]

Answer (score 1):

There is no mate in the next move but very good move is Qd1!
You always may use online tools to calculate next move.
For example http://www.chessnextmove.com